# Sorting references in both number and alphabetic manner

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Consider the following text

```
\documentclass[pageno]{jpaper}
\begin{document}

Technology has been introduced in various ways \cite{HAR02}. 
One of them is the usage of mobile phones\cite{LIU07, AKR09}.

\bstctlcite{bstctl:etal, bstctl:nodash, bstctl:simpurl}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

And the bib file contains

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{bstctl:etal,
  CTLuse_forced_etal = {no},
  CTLmax_names_forced_etal = {3},
} 

@IEEtranBSTCTL{bstctl:nodash,
  CTLdash_repeated_names = {no},
}

@IEEEtranBSTCTL{bstctl:simpurl,
  CTLname_url_prefix = {Available: },
}

@article{HAR02,
  Author = {A. Author},
  Title = {The Title},
  Year = {2002}
}

@article{AKR09,
  Author = {B. Akreman},
  Title = {The Title},
  Year = {2009}
}

@article{LIU07,
  Author = {C. Liu},
  Title = {The Title},
  Year = {2007}
}
```

The output looks like

```
Technology has been introduced in various ways [2]. 
One of them is the usage of mobile phones [3, 1].


 References:
 [1] B. Akreman ...
 [2] A. Haris ...
 [3] C. Liu ...
```

The references are sorted alphabetically (as stated by `IEEEtranS`) However the problem is the second set of references are not sorted ascending. As you can see it is `[3, 1]`. I want to see `[1, 3]`.

You may say that I can manually change the order of `\cite{LIU07, AKR09}` to `\cite{AKR09, LIU07}` but for large number of citations in various places it is error prone. Also it is not very good to see `[12, 3, 15, 13, 5, 30]`.

Is there any way to have globally sorted in alphabetical order and locally sort by numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load the [`cite`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite) package; it will sort and compress references for you:

```
\documentclass[pageno]{jpaper}
\usepackage{cite}

% this section just for the example %%%%%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{HAR02,
  Author = {A. Author},
  Title = {The Title},
  Year = {2002}
}

@article{AKR09,
  Author = {B. Akreman},
  Title = {The Title},
  Year = {2009}
}

@article{LIU07,
  Author = {C. Liu},
  Title = {The Title},
  Year = {2007}
}
\end{filecontents*}
% this section just for the example %%%%%

\begin{document}

Technology has been introduced in various ways \cite{HAR02}. 
One of them is the usage of mobile phones\cite{LIU07, AKR09}.

\bstctlcite{bstctl:etal, bstctl:nodash, bstctl:simpurl}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that you have integrated tex and bib files. If I have two separated files, should I use `\usepackage{filecontents}    
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}     \end{filecontents*}` in the bib file?

Comment: @mahmood No. As my code indicates the section with `filecontents*` is just for the example in my answer. You can have your `.bib` and `.tex` files separate, as you usually do.